# How to add markers and store them in a model attribute using Google Maps api and Play framework

Tags: java, javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, playframework

I'm currently trying to develop a web app with Play and thereby I would like to integrate Google Maps which works quite well so far.

In this app, the user should be able to add a marker by entering an address. This address has to be coded to get the LatLng values and the marker should be display on map as long as the user doesn't delete it.

My code looks like this:

As you can see, I added one example marker at the beginning. Adding a new one works very well. But when I refresh the whole page, Google Maps is reloading again and only displays the example marker but none of the new ones.

My questions:

1) Is it possible to let Google Maps remeber the new markers when they are available?

2) Is there any possibility to store the LatLng values in a Play model as an String attribute? This could help me to reload all positions from the DB while reloading the Map and redisplay all the markers. But it seems to be impossible to run the codeAdress() function inside a play statement like this: @{Place.store(codeAddress())}. This doesn't work.

Main.html (template for every html page)

```
<head>
....
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=-mykey-&sensor=false">

</script>
<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/maps.js'}" type="text/javascript"
    charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>
</head>
```

Maps.js:

```
function initialize() {

    var latlngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(12.345, 12.345);
    var latlngExample = new google.maps.LatLng(12.345, 12.345);

    var mapOptions = {
        center : latlngCenter,
        zoom : 12,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    var contentString = 'text';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content : contentString
    });

    var pinColor = "72EC0E";
    var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|"
                    + pinColor, new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
            new google.maps.Size(40, 37), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(12, 35));

    var markerExample = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : latlngExample,
        map : map,
        icon : pinImage,
        shadow : pinShadow,
        title : 'Title'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerExample, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, markerExample);
    });

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

}

function codeAddress(query) {
    var address = query;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address' : address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map : map,
                position : results[0].geometry.location
            });
            alert("Alert1");
        } else {
            alert("No result");
        }
    });
    return results[0].geometry.location;
}
```

index.html (extending from main)

```
#{field 'parking.street'} <label for="street">street</label> <input
            type="text" class="form-control" name="${field.name}" id="address"
            maxlength="50" placeholder="street"> #{/field}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="codeAddress()">add</button>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can keep all of the markers a user adds inside of a javascript array. This would allow you to keep track of all the markers the user adds for the current page load.  Because you keep track of the markers you could do things like remove the markers from the map, if you wanted.
2. I am not familiar with java or play, but if java/play is rendering your template, calling a javascript function `codeAddress` will not work.  perhaps the easiest way to persist a user added marker would create a controller method something like `/marker/add` and make an ajax request to that method everytime a user adds a marker.